# How to know which tab is selected and active in in the set of dynamic generated tabs on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know the language tab selected while uploading file from the set of dynamic generated tabs. It should also pass the language selected from the highlighted tab i.e 1st one in the snapshot below

Here I have selected Chinese language tab form the 4th set. I have chosen 4rd set from which the file will be uploaded. Now I need to recognize the selected language to pass the value via my ajax call.

[image]

I am using the command `console.log($("ul.nav-tabs li.active a").text());`which gives result as `"ChineseEnglishChineseChinese"` which shows languages active from all the tabs. I need only from the 4th i.e. only `"Chinese"`. Please let me know if you know how to do.

Below is the function to add new tabs:

```
function buildTabsNew() {
    var questions = jsonResponse;
    var newTabs = [];
    var langlength = questions[0].DetailLanguages.length;
    console.log(questions[0].DetailLanguages);
    for (var k = 0; k < langlength; k++) {
        counter++;
        languageSelected = questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name;
        var tabsArray = {
            paneId: "paneid-" + counter,
            title: questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name,
            content: '<textarea class="textarea-' + hash + k + '" placeholder="' + questions[0].DetailLanguages[k].Language_Name + '" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;"></textarea><div id="uploadFile-' + hash + k + '"></div>',
            active: k == 0 ? true : false,
            disabled: false
        };
        newTabs.push(tabsArray);
        console.log(newTabs);
    }
```

Comment: can you please add codepen link ?

Comment: please provide us with your code

Comment: @Priyanka While it's a good idea to request that the user provides a working example, It would be better to suggest that the OP use the snippet tool `<>` on StackOverflow so we keep everything on the same site.

Comment: Impossible to tell from that fuzzy picture.  Do you have nested tabs?  Do you have multiple tabs?  If yes, you need to be more specific *which* tabs you want, eg `$("ul.nav-tabs.language-selection > li.active").text()` or `$("ul.nav-tabs.language-selection > li.active > a").text()`

Comment: I have changed the picture to clearer one.